# Limitations on running Windows on latest Macbook Pro

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I'm strongly considering to buy latest Macbook Pro because of the hardware (i5 with Quad core) and design. I'm a Windows IT Pro and virtualization is a hard requirement for me, in addition to running Windows 10 most of the time. Would there be any limitations in terms of virtualization or other functionality in Windows I should be aware of or would it be just like buying any other high end computer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! How will you be running Windows 10 on the MacBook? Natively or in a virtualised environment?

Comment: You're buying the latest MBP because of the *hardware and design*?  I **absolutely love** Apple but wouldn't touch the latest MBPs with a 10 foot pole because of their *hardware and design*.  Thermal issues, keyboard (failures/horrible typing experience), and dongle madness are just a few of the issues at the top of the list.

Comment: If you're going to use virtualization, there are no issues.  I use VirtualBox on an iMac with zerio issues.  Bootcamp can be finicky with drivers from time to time and IMO (very inconvenient to switch from one OS to the other). In the end, a Mac is a PC with a custom EFI.  I would do VM long before I do Bootcamp

Comment: i5 ? I thought the latest are sporting i7 or i9 processors...

Comment: According to Norwegian Apple Store website there is also new 13" models with i5, which I believe makes sense as it has quad core. In terms of the thermal problems they seem to be fixed. I don't necessarily need the newest edition but I want to buy one that has not been previously used. Most important is to know I can run BootCamp and have Hyper-V with full virtualization support.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks! I wan't to run Windows 10 natively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need macOS to download the drivers needed to install Windows 10. Once you have the drivers, you can install Windows 10 with or without macOS. Windows 10 will EFI boot and operate the same as any other new PC. There should be no limitations in terms of virtualization or other functionality in Windows.

Comment: This answer is not correct. user299397's answer is the correct one.

Comment: @Palmi: If you have knowledge that an answer is in error, then edit the answer. If the change is not accepted, then you can still leave a comment.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't realize that this is the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Hyper-V is supported unless something has changed.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/31049104#31049104